# Does the Nakajima-Zwanzig equation preserve the trace of the projected density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Looking at the [Nakajima-Zwanzig equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakajima-Zwanzig_equation),  wich gives the time evolution of a projection $\cal {P} \rho$  of a full density matrix $\rho$, I am wondering if the trace of $\cal P \rho$  is preserved under time evolution.

The terms like $LX \stackrel{def}= \dfrac{i}{\hbar} [X,H]$ have a null trace, but  it seems there is no reason why terms like $\mathcal {P} L X$ necessarily have a null trace, so it seems that the trace of the projected density matrix is not necessarily conserved.

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the canonical choice $\mathcal{P}X = \mathrm{Tr}_B(X)\otimes\rho_B$, where $B$ denotes the irrelevant degrees of freedom in the total Hilbert space $\mathbb{H} = \mathbb{H}_A \otimes \mathbb{H}_B$, and $\rho_B$ is an arbitrary reference state on $\mathbb{H}_B$, then $$ \mathrm{Tr} (\mathcal{P} L X )= \mathrm{Tr} (\mathrm{Tr}_B(LX)\otimes\rho_B) = \mathrm{Tr}_A(\mathrm{Tr}_B(LX))\times\mathrm{Tr}_B(\rho_B) = \mathrm{Tr}(LX) = 0. $$
I expect similar reasoning will show that the full Nakajima-Zwanzig (NZ) equation is trace-preserving. This must be the case since it is formally equivalent to the von-Neumann equation. However, usually one makes some approximation to the NZ equation, such as truncating the time propagator for the irrelevant subspace $e^{\mathcal{Q}Lt}$ to zeroth or maybe lowest non-trivial order in $L$ (the first order term typically vanishes). In this case there is no guarantee of a physical (completely positive) evolution. However, it still looks like even such a truncated NZ equation must be trace-preserving by the same argument, since it is formulated in terms of commutators that vanish under the trace operation.

I don't know how to prove it for other definitions of the projection $\mathcal{P}$, but the choice I have used is by far the most common (if not the only) one in use in the open quantum systems literature.

Comment: +1 : So, if I understand correctly, with a usual reduced density matrix $\mathcal{P} \rho = Tr_B(\rho)$, I will have : $\partial_t Tr(\mathcal{P}\rho) = 0$ ?

Comment: @Trimok Yes, that's right.

Comment: I don't think the statement about approximations is correct for every context, approximating the NZ equation seems to be quite notorious for not being trace-preserving etc. (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6218). +1 on the answer though, was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

OP links to the Wikipedia page for the [Nakajima-Zwanzig equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakajima-Zwanzig_equation).
Now, let ${\cal H}$ be the Hilbert space of the full system and ${\cal H}_{\rm red}$ be the Hilbert space of the reduced system. The [density operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) $\rho\in B({\cal H})$ should be [semipositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element) and have trace one.

What is perhaps not emphasized sufficiently on Wikipedia is 
that the reduced/projected density matrix $\rho_{\rm red}={\cal P}\rho\in B({\cal H}_{\rm red})$ should also have the properties of a density matrix, i.e. be a semipositive operator $\rho_{\rm red}:{\cal H}_{\rm red}\to {\cal H}_{\rm red}$ with trace one.

The above conditions lead to severe constraints on the type of projection ${\cal P}$ that we can allow in the first place. In fact, generically we can only suggest the canonical reduction construction via tensor product splitting:

$$\text{system } ~=~ \text{ environment } \otimes \text{ reduced system}, $$

i.e.  ${\cal H}={\cal H}_{\rm env}\otimes {\cal H}_{\rm red}$, so that 
${\cal P}\rho={\rm tr}_{{\cal H}_{\rm env}} \rho,$ 
cf. Mark Mitchison's answer.

*Example (which ultimately doesn't work):* Consider the Hilbert spaces ${\cal H}=\mathbb{C}^2$ and ${\cal H}_{\rm red}=\mathbb{C}$. Let the Hamiltonian be $H=\frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega\sigma_{1}$, Here $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, and $\sigma_3$ are the Pauli matrices. Define

$$\sigma_{\pm}~:=~\frac{1}{2}({\bf 1}_{2 \times 2}\pm \sigma_3).$$

Let

$$\rho(t)~=~\frac{1}{2}({\bf 1}_{2 \times 2} +\sigma(t))$$

belong to the [Bloch ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere). Let $\sigma(t=0)=\sigma_2$ be a initial condition. Then

$$\sigma(t)~=~e^{Lt}\sigma_2~=~\sin(\omega t)\sigma_3 +\cos(\omega t)\sigma_2,$$

which happens to correspond to pure states. The projection ${\cal P}$ to spin up ($\uparrow$) is

$$\rho_{\rm red}(t)~:=~{\cal P}\rho(t)~:=~\sigma_{+}\rho(t)\sigma_{+}~=~\frac{1}{2}(1 +\sin(\omega t)),$$

which doesn't have trace one.

Comment: Btw, the tensor product of the two Hilbert spaces is aka as a _bipartite_ system.